# Illegal pream-token in tabular

Tags: tables, errors

I'm having trouble constructing a `tabular` environment and compiling it with `pdflatex`. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Left side FBD} \label{tab:title2}
\begin{tabular}{ C C }\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf X & \b
f Y \\\midrule
$0$ & $-F_g$\\
$F_t \sin \theta$ & $F_t \cos \theta$\\
$-F_e$ & $0$\\
\bottomrule[1.25pt]
$0$ & $0$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

However, I then get the following error:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 \begin{tabular}{ C C }
                          \toprule[1.5pt]

! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used.
```

I've tried giving each `C` and argument as I've seen in other source code (I'm still not certain exactly what that argument is for) I get another error message. When I replace `C` with `C{.85in}` I now get:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 \begin{tabular}{ C{.85in} C{.85in} }
                                        \toprule[1.5pt]

! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (.85in): `c' used.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with my `tabular`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Use a small `c` instead of `C`: `\begin{tabular}{ c c }`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

here is the fixed MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Left side FBD} \label{tab:title2}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf X & \b
f Y \\\midrule
$0$ & $-F_g$\\
$F_t \sin \theta$ & $F_t \cos \theta$\\
$-F_e$ & $0$\\
\bottomrule[1.25pt]
$0$ & $0$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

C should be replaced with c

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between the lower and upper case c's anyway?

Comment: @David: The difference is the case, and LaTeX (like many programming languages) use a case-specific interface. So, just like you use `\sin` and not `\Sin` or `\SIN`. There is a difference, since LaTeX expects a lowercase `l`, `c`, `r`, `p` by default. [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) provides an additional `X`, while [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) adds `m` and allow expansion of the defaults to your liking.