# "Illegal pream-token (]) used." for array

Tags: errors, arrays

I have an identical error message as the one in [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110333/illegal-pream-token-in-tabular/) However upon applying the solution in the answer, the errors still occur.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\subsection{b)}
$2x^3+5x^2-7x+3$\\
$\sisetup{table-format=1.1}
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{array}{S|SSSr[table-format=-1]}
1 & 2 & 5 & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{-7} & \multicolumn{1}{S}{3}\\
& & 2 & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{7}\\
\cline{2-4}
2 & 2 & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{S}{0} \\
&  & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{4} \\
\cline{2-3}
3 & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{2} &\multicolumn{1}{r}{11} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{S|}{ }\\
\cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{3}{S}{2}
\end{array}$\\
\vspace{2mm}
$\therefore 2x^3+5x^2-7x+3 = 2x(x-1)(x-2) + 11x(x-1)+3$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to add vertical space after ``\\``, use ``\\[2mm]``; the `\vspace{2mm}` after `$` adds the space *below* the formula, not above it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to not passing an option to the `r` column type (which doesn't take any options), you may want to reorganize and streamline the code of the `array` environment, say, along the following lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\therefore' macro
\begin{document}
\subsection{b)}

$2x^3+5x^2-7x+3$\\
\sisetup{table-format=-1.0}

\medskip\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{}r|SSS|S}
1 & 2 & 5 & -7 & 3\\
  &   & 2 &  7 \\
\cline{2-4}
2 & 2 & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{S}{0} \\ 
  &   & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{4} \\
\cline{2-3}
3 & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{2} &\multicolumn{1}{r}{11} \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{S|}{}\\
\cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & 2
\end{array}$

\medskip\noindent
$\therefore 2x^3+5x^2-7x+3 = 2x(x-1)(x-2) + 11x(x-1)+3$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`r` columns does not take options, `S` columns do. So move that `[....]` to after an `S` column