# Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (2cm): `c' used

Tags: tables, tabularx

My question is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110333/illegal-pream-token-in-tabular/) But it seems different.
I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\section{Selected courses}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ m{8cm} m{6.5cm} r{2cm} }
 C & C & C \\
 C & C & C \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

My code was working last month without error. but I opened it today and got this error:

```
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (2cm): `c' used.
See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                                                                            
l.295 ...\begin{tabular}{ m{8cm} m{6.5cm} r{2cm} }
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

I think it's maybe related to the package update.

Comment: The r column type does not allow an argument for the width.

Comment: Replace `r{...}` with `wr{...}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could turn your good question into a great question if you turned the code into a syntactically valid LaTeX document. It is only missing the `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. That way the code you show avoids spurious errors and actually reproduces (only) your problem. (I can't offer the incentive that I will upvote your question if you do that, because I already voted.)

Comment: "My code was working last month without error" no, that has never worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `r` column type does not allow an argument for the width. If you'd like a fixed width column with right aligned text, you could use something like this (I added vertical boarders `|` so one can see the alignment and made the columns much smaller so they fit on the page):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\section{Selected courses}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |m{3cm} |m{3.5cm}| >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{2cm}| }
 C & C & C \\
 C & C & C \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note celdors comment, might be an idea to start promoting it.

Comment: @daleif I'm looking forward to upvote their answer!